# Can a child class creates object of type super class that is abstract?

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm not sure if I asked this correctly but I'm given in an assignment

ClassA is abstract

ClassB extends Class A

then in main method of ClassB we have:

ClassA obj = new ClassB();

What's happening here and what's the purpose of doing so?

Comment: What do _you_ think is happening?

Comment: I understand that if a child inherits super then an object of super/child can be created. but i'm confused cause i know that we can't create object of an abstract

Comment: You are not creating object of abstract class. You are creating object of `ClassB` and *assigning* it to reference of type `ClassA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can never create an object that is from an abstract class. Ever. Period.

Here your **variable** that gets assigned the object is of abstract type, but the object itself that the variable refers to is not and never can be. The distinction between a reference and a reference variable is a key concept that must be understood to advance, but once you get it, you'll go "a-ha!".

Answer (score 2):

This really is a major part of polymorphism. First off, yes, the code you wrote is exactly how it would happen. I think the easiest way to understand it (for me anyway) is to look at how a game would behave.

Super class Item is abstract
In this Item class we have variables for the textures/ids/names etc, of the items.

Then we make our child classes of the Item superclass, these would be all of the items in their more specific areas, (for example, weapons, currency, food, etc). And of course in their classes they'll have the details that help make them stand out.

So finally. Why? Well if you have to load all of these items, it would be an absolute pain to specify all of the different child's individually. You could, for example, put all child classes into an array, a list, or a map. All of which would be under the Item class name. This way, all of the child classes of the superclass can all be put into one container for easy manipulation of all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

yes this is entirely possible. so an abstract class is like a contract. you will provide only method declaration in an Abstract class. It is the child class's responsibility to provide definitions. Hence Class B would be responsible for defining the behavior of any methods that Class A declares. we do this if we want to enforce a default behavior in the child classes. read up on the documentation for more details and examples.